# Not getting OS X El Capitan Public Beta updates

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, software-update, beta-seed-program

I'm registered for getting Public Beta updates, but in the last 4-5 months, I'm not receiving any updates in the Mac App Store.

I'm currently on 10.11 Beta (15A278b).

Comment: Are you signed in with your Apple ID on the computer?

Comment: Is it just 10.11? Or are you on 10.11.X? If 10.11, apple isn't providing public beta's for that version. If on 10.11.X, grgarside answer is correct

Comment: @Angelplayer Yes, I'm signed in with my Apple ID.

Comment: @Jules I've also mentioned the build. I'm on OS X 10.11 (15A278b).

Comment: @Satyajeet I would try to re-register with the public beta program then

Answer (score 4):

Go to System Preferences → App Store and ensure ‘your computer is set to receive beta updates’.

[image]

Comment: I checked but there's no option for 'beta software updates' on System Preferences/App Store.[You can see here](https://jumpshare.com/v/Y2tfSFrtRiltOK6XEUSt)